# Unable to take getText()

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi i am learning selenium. i am trying to take geText() of username from index page of FreeCrm.com, my xpath is correct from firebug. but getting `NoSuchElementExceptopn`.

**Url**: https://www.freecrm.com
**My Code**:

```
    @Test(description="verify the account holder name displaying correctly or not")
        public void AccHolderName() {
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.freecrm.com/index.html");
            driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxxx");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-small']")).click();
            String AccName=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='headertable']//table//tbody//td[@class='headertext' and @align='left']")).getText().trim();
            System.out.println(AccName);
```

**Error**:Unable to locate element:

```
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[@class='headertable']//table//tbody//td[@class='headertext' and @align='left']"}
```

Plz help me with code

Comment: Don't share credentials. Post the relevant html instead.

Comment: the item that you are looking to read from the DOM may not be rendered once the base page is rendered, I mean it may be rendered via AJAX so you need to wait until the element will be visible on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your element is in frame, you have to switch to its content first:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).wait(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("mainpanel")));
```

Than you have to wait until element will be visible on the page:

```
// wait at least 10 seconds until element will be visible on tha page
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='headertable']//table//tbody//td[@class='headertext' and @align='left']"))));
String AccName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='headertable']//table//tbody//td[@class='headertext' and @align='left']")).getText().trim();
System.out.println(AccName);

//switch back to default content
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

***Note:*** you have to add some imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

Comment: Thank u sooooo Much :)